# Creating an external tool to edit Unreal project optimization settings

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, dll

#### INTRO

I am creating a C++ app that will help users to set up optimization settings in the Unreal game engine. I want to let the program make all this work on its own. This application is being written for Windows 10 platform (maybe it will be cross-platform in the future).

---

#### PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

To make the program working as intended, I must be able to change configuration files, add some UE objects to the project and call editor functions (e.g. rebuild lights).

---

#### MY SOLUTION

I can parse some of the `.ini` files and edit them. However, the real problem is with UE objects and editor functions. One of the possible ways is to get symbols from the `.dll` and run that function in a separate process. Another way is to use the actual UE4 code for these tasks.

---

#### QUESTION

Is there any easier and safer way to achieve what I need?

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question - why are you not implementing it as an Unreal plugin?

Comment: @Rotem , Actually, the moderator changed my question, so it is unclear now. I am creating an app that will support various engines. It means that you just open the app, choose an engine, set some properties, and it does all the work for you.

Comment: Your app could include and install an Unreal plugin and communicate with it via RPC

Comment: Im also curious who you see as the target audience for a multi-engine app. Don't developers develop their game only in one engine?

Comment: @Rotem, That's a good suggestion. I was too excited about the idea of creating an app that would help people to optimize their projects. I wanted to create a universal application that you install and work with any of the supported engines. However, now I understand that there is no real need of doing this all-in-one stuff.